# How to remove `User-Agent` from email header?

Tags: mutt

I'd like to remove this line from the header of the email sent by mutt.

```
User-Agent: Mutt/1.12.0 (2019-05-25)
```

Could anybody let me know how to do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Add `set user_agent=no` to your `~/.muttrc`.